# caching json data after specific time period in android

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am having trouble in displaying `Json` data.

I want to fetch data and save it in the database then refresh data to be updated every 24 hours.

But in my code every time I access the `webservice` for displaying data, I want is the database to be updated after 24 hours and rest of the time values to be displayed from database.

**Code:**

```
public class Banking_Economics extends ListActivity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    ProgressDialog pd;
    ListView lv;

    SQLiteDB db;
    SQLiteDatabase sdb;

    private static final String CurrentAffairs = "CurrentAffairs";

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:53159/WebSite5/Default2.aspx";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_FILE_NAME = "tests";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    // private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
    public final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> testList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();;
    public final ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();;

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray tests;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.banking_eco);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        // db=new SQLiteDB(Banking_Economics.this);
        sdb = openOrCreateDatabase("me1.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        /*
         * Log.i("In BankingEconomics","creating table"); String sql=
         * "create table CurrentAffairs(id integer primary key autoincrement, message varchar)"
         * ; sdb.execSQL(sql); Log.i("In BankingEconomics","table created");
         * Toast.makeText(this, "your table is created",
         * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         */
        /*
         * sql="delete from Questions where aliasname=28"; db.execSQL(sql);
         * Log.i("In BankingEconomics","Records deleted...");
         */
        // db.close();


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    boolean connected = false;
                    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
                        if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || 
                                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                            //we are connected to a network
                            connected = true;
                            //Toast.makeText(Banking_Economics.this, "network connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            json();
                            //disp();
                        }
                        else{
                            connected = false;
                           // Toast.makeText(Banking_Economics.this, "network not connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           // disp();
                        }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            // stuff that updates ui
                            /**
                             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                             * */

                            disp();

                        }

                    });

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();
        // new LoadList().execute();
        // sdb.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void disp() {
        try {
            Cursor c;
            // c=db.getAllData();
            String sql = "select * from CurrentAffairs LIMIT 10";
            c = sdb.rawQuery(sql, null);
            if (c != null) {
                // if (c.moveToNext()) {
                while (c.moveToNext()) {

                    String message = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("message"));
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                    // value
                    map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                    result.add(message);

                }// while(c.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.i("In Banking economics", "Error-" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Banking_Economics.this, result,R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_MESSAGE },new int[] { R.id.textView1 });
        ListAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,R.id.textView1, result);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        // selecting single ListView item
        lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String message = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), News.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                startActivity(in);

            }

        });
    }

    public void json(){
        // Your implementation
        // Hashmap for ListView
        File file = new File ("CurrentAffairs");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        //System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, +24);
        long mSec = calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

        //String formattedDate = df.format(calendar.getTime());
        //Date z=df.parse(formattedDate);
        //long date=file.lastModified();
        if(file.exists()){
            if(file.lastModified()+mSec>System.currentTimeMillis()){
                final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> testList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                // Creating JSON Parser instance
                Jsonparse jParser = new Jsonparse();
                Log.i("in Main activity", "Jsonparse object declared");

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                Log.i("in Main activity", "JSON object declared");

                try {
                    // Getting Array of Contacts
                    tests = json.getJSONArray(TAG_FILE_NAME);
                    Log.i("in Main activity", "JSON array called");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < tests.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = tests.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String message = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                        Log.i("In run", "" + message);
                        // adding each record to database
                        // ContentValues content=new ContentValues();
                        // content.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                        // db.insert(message);
                        Log.i("In run", "" + message);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        testList.add(map);

                        // Log.i("In SingleMenuItem Activity","inserting values in Questions");
                        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
                        content.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                        Log.i("In SingleMenuItem Activity",
                                "inserted Ques_no");

                        sdb.insertOrThrow(CurrentAffairs, null, content);
                        // Log.i("In SingleMenuItem Activity","inserted values in Questions");

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i("In Main", "" + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{}
        }else{final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> testList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        Jsonparse jParser = new Jsonparse();
        Log.i("in Main activity", "Jsonparse object declared");

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        Log.i("in Main activity", "JSON object declared");

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            tests = json.getJSONArray(TAG_FILE_NAME);
            Log.i("in Main activity", "JSON array called");

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < tests.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = tests.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String message = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                Log.i("In run", "" + message);
                // adding each record to database
                // ContentValues content=new ContentValues();
                // content.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                // db.insert(message);
                Log.i("In run", "" + message);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                testList.add(map);

                // Log.i("In SingleMenuItem Activity","inserting values in Questions");
                ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
                content.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                Log.i("In SingleMenuItem Activity",
                        "inserted Ques_no");

                sdb.insertOrThrow(CurrentAffairs, null, content);
                // Log.i("In SingleMenuItem Activity","inserted values in Questions");

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.i("In Main", "" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}


        //getjson();
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have tried the solutions from similar questions but it's not working.

I have tried using broadcast receiver and alarmManager but its still not working. I want changes in the code so that it should call json function only once a day.

Comment: Is your data getting cleared after 24 hrs. ?

Comment: no my data isn't getting cleared after 24 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes made to code:

```
boolean connected = false;
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
                    if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || 
                            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        //we are connected to a network
                        connected = true;
                        //Toast.makeText(Banking_Economics.this, "network connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //File file = new File ("CurrentAffairs");
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        //System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
                        calendar.setTime(new Date());
                        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +1);
                        long mSec = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                        Intent it=new Intent(Current_Affairs.this,MyReceiver.class);
                        pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Current_Affairs.this, 0, it, 0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, mSec, pendingIntent);    
                        /*if(file.exists()){
                            if(file.lastModified()+mSec>System.currentTimeMillis()){
                                json();
                                //disp();
                            }else{
                            }
                        }else{
                            json();
                            //disp();
                        }*/

                        //disp();
                    }
                    else{
                        connected = false;
                       // Toast.makeText(Banking_Economics.this, "network not connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       // disp();
                    }
```

BroadCastReceiver Code:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Current_Affairs ca=new Current_Affairs();
        ca.json();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be :-

1.Fetch data from server , parse it and store in DB.

2.) After 24 hrs fire a query to delete all the database. This can be done using broadcast receivers and alarm manager.

3.) Every time app is accessed check weather your database has any data. If yes, show data from database else fetch data from server.

If you need any detailed explanation on above points . Ask me

EDIT

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TAB", null);
if (cur != null ) {
cur.moveToFirst();                    
if (cur.getInt (0)> 0) {              
    // table has data . Show data from table 
    // eg. tv.setText(cur.getInt(0))
    }
}
```

}

Moreover to update database, use broadcast receiver and fire update query if database is not empty else fire create queries.

Comment: Actually I dont want to clear the database I just want to update it with new information (if avaiable) after 24 hours. Also can you give an example of " Every time app is accessed check weather your database has any data. If yes, show data from database else fetch data from server".

Comment: in that case you just have to show data from database      .I have edited my answer for your query

Comment: I have tried it but its still not working. Can you please suggest another way?